# Creating a number range with proportions using siunitx

Tags: siunitx, sirange

I'd like to create a range of proprtions, something like

> 1:2 to 1:4

I'm using `siunitx` package, however when I write `\numrange{1:2}{1:4}`, I get

```
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number" Invalid token ':' in numerical input. For immediate help type H <return>. This is my range \numrange{1:2}{1:4}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
This is my range \numrange{1:2}{1:4}
\end{document}
```

any hint?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the options `input-decimal-markers` and `output-decimal-marker` to set a `:` as decimal point. This can be done locally with

```
\numrange[input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:]{1:2}{1:4}
```

or globaly with

```
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:}
```

But I wouldn't recommend the latter, because it will affect all numbers.

You can also define a macro for this

**Edit:** added optional parameter to enable using additional options.

```
\newcommand{\proprange}[3][]{%
  \numrange[input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:,#1]{#2}{#3}%
}
```

which can then be used just like `\numrange`. I think is the best solution, if you need this several times.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
% uncomment next line to make it global
%\sisetup{input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:}
\newcommand{\proprange}[3][]{%
  \numrange[input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:,#1]{#2}{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
This is my range \numrange[input-decimal-markers=:,output-decimal-marker=:]{1:2}{1:4}
or this \proprange{1:3}{1:6}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:**

Since you want to use decimal numbers, `:` can't be used as decimal marker.
But macros for proportions can be written.

Here is an example defining two commands `\prop` and `\proprange` for this.
Both use `\num` internally and have an optional argument passed to `\num`, so `siunitx` options can be used.

The macros can be used in text and in math. In text a line break can occur before or after the *to*. In inline math there will be no line break.

If you want proportions and/or porportion ranges with alignment on decimal point, colon, and the *to* special column definition are needed (see code below). The macros can only be used for single columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\prop}[2][]{%
  \@prop[#1]#2\@prop@end
}
\newcommand{\@prop}{}
\def\@prop[#1]#2:#3\@prop@end{%
  \ensuremath{\num[#1]{#2}\text{\,:\,}\num[#1]{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\proprange}[3][]{%
  \ifmmode
    \prop[#1]{#2}\text{ to }\prop[#1]{#3}%
  \else
    \prop[#1]{#2} to \prop[#1]{#3}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is my range \proprange{1:2.6}{1:3.6}
or this \proprange{.5:1.3}{.5:1.8}
or with optional arguments for \verb|\num|
\proprange[add-integer-zero=false]{.5:3}{.5:6}
in text there may be a line break \proprange{.5:1.3}{.5:1.8}
but not, if it's in inline math (fillfillfillfillfillfillfillfill) $\proprange{.537:1.3}{.537:1.8}$

In equations:
\[
  \prop{.5:1.3} = \prop{1:2.6}
\]

\[
  \proprange{.5:1.3}{.5:1.8} = \proprange{1:2.6}{1:3.6}
\]

\[
  \proprange[add-integer-zero=false]{.5:1.3}{.5:1.8} = \proprange{1:2.6}{1:3.6}
\]

In tables \verb|\prop| and \verb|\proprange| can only be used for single columns.
To adjust on decimal point, colon, and the ``to'' special column declarations are
needed.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lS@{\,:\,}S}\toprule
\textsf{which} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsf{proportion}} \\\midrule
first proportion  & 1   &  2.6  \\
second proportion & 1   & 12.65 \\
third proportion  & 0.5 &  2.6  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2ex}
\begin{tabular}{lS@{\,:\,}S@{ to }S@{\,:\,}S}\toprule
\textsf{which} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textsf{proportion range}} \\\midrule
first range  & 1   & 2.6   & 1   &  3.6  \\
second range & 1   & 12.65 & 1   & 15.37 \\
third range  & 0.5 & 2.6   & 0.5 &  1.8  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It solved partially, thanks!. One more question, If my proportion is decimal, like `1:2.5`

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. Do you really need `siunitx` for this? How about `\newcommand{\proprange}[2]{#1 to #2}`?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. see edit 2 in my answer